git bare repository tree view like GitHub
I'm trying to view git bare repository tracked file in CLI on my local machine, similarly how they display on GitHub (or any other git hosting provider).
Example:
"Minimal", equivalent of tree --dirsfirst:
.
├── src
│   ├── file-1
│   └── file-2
├── README.md
└── LICENSE

"Advanced", more like git hosting site, for example GitHub:
.
├── src        commit-message-1 1 hour ago
│   ├── file-1 commit-message-1 1 hour ago
│   └── file-2 commit-message-2 8 days ago
├── README.md  commit-message-3 year ago
└── LICENSE    commit-message-3 year ago

It would need to be colored to make it more readable but I hope I get my point across.
"Extra advanced" example would be example 2 ("Advanced") but interactive where you could navigate directories like with lf or yazi.
I know I could just use tree to achieve "minimal" example but I don't think I can use tree with git bare repository.
I know about git ls-files but that doesn't render file list in tree like view and I was hoping for more advanced view with commit messages, hashes and dates but even that would be something.
When searching for a solution, nearly all questions/answers I found were mentioning git ls-tree which is not what I want.

Why do you not want git ls-tree?

@mkrieger1 because git ls-tree doesn't render a "tree" view like tree does, it just a flat list,

If you just want to browse HEAD, the simplest way is probably to create a worktree and browse that.
